# Laraver Orchid Выгрузка в excel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, orchid

Есть проект он на laravel 8, для админки установлен orchid, на одной странцие я выгружаю пользователей в excel файл, нужно чтобы данная выгрузка учитывала установленный фильтр. Вот каку меня сейчас выглядит файл:

```
public function query(): iterable {
    return [
        'participant' => Profile::when(Auth::user()->organizer_id, function (Builder $query) {
            return $query->where('organizer_id', Auth::user()->organizer_id);
        })->filters()->defaultSort('id', 'desc')->paginate(),
    ];
}

public function commandBar(): iterable {
    return [
        Button::make('Выгрузить в Excel')
            ->method('export')
            ->icon('cloud-download'),
    ];
}

public function export(Request $request) {
    $profiles = Profile::when(Auth::user()->organizer_id, function (Builder $query) {
        return $query->where('organizer_id', Auth::user()->organizer_id);
    })->filters()->select('external_id', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'patronymic', 'phone', 'email', 'gender',
        'date_of_birth', 'status')->defaultSort('id', 'desc')->get();

    $fileArray = array_merge([['Внешний id', 'Фамилия', 'Имя', 'Отчество', 'Номер телефона',
        'Email', 'Пол', 'Дата рождения', 'Статус']], $profiles->toArray());

    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $activeWorksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $activeWorksheet->getStyle('A1:I' . count($fileArray))->getNumberFormat()
        ->setFormatCode(NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);

    $widthColumn = '20';
    $activeWorksheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth($widthColumn);
    $activeWorksheet->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth($widthColumn);
    $activeWorksheet->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth($widthColumn);
    $activeWorksheet->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth($widthColumn);
    $activeWorksheet->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth($widthColumn);
    $activeWorksheet->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth($widthColumn);
    $activeWorksheet->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth($widthColumn);
    $activeWorksheet->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth($widthColumn);
    $activeWorksheet->getColumnDimension('I')->setWidth($widthColumn);

    $activeWorksheet->fromArray($fileArray);

    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);

    return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($writer) {
        $writer->save('php://output');
    }, 'profiles.xlsx', [
        'Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="profiles.xlsx"',
        'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
        'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT',
        'Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate',
        'Pragma: public'
    ]);
}
```

Это работает и выгружает пользователей, но как мне передавайть в export данные для фильтра, я ума не приложу. В $request данных фильтра нету. Нужна ваша помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге получилось сделать вот так, хотя похоже на костыль:

```
public function commandBar(): iterable
{
    return [
        Button::make('Выгрузить в Excel')
            ->method('export', $_GET['filter'] ?? [])
            ->icon('cloud-download')
            ->rawClick()
            ->novalidate(),
    ];
}

public function export(Request $request): StreamedResponse
{
    $profiles = Profile::when(Auth::user()->organizer_id, function (Builder $query) {
        return $query->where('organizer_id', Auth::user()->organizer_id);
    })->select('external_id', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'patronymic', 'phone', 'email', 'gender',
        'date_of_birth', 'status')->defaultSort('id', 'desc');

    $filter = $request->all();
    unset($filter['_token']);

    if (!empty($filter)) {
        foreach ($filter as $key => $value) {
            $profiles->where($key, $value);
        }
    }

    $result = $profiles->get()->toArray();

    $fileArray = array_merge([['Внешний id', 'Фамилия', 'Имя', 'Отчество', 'Номер телефона',
        'Email', 'Пол', 'Дата рождения', 'Статус']], $result);

    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $activeWorksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $activeWorksheet->getStyle('A1:I' . count($fileArray))->getNumberFormat()
        ->setFormatCode(NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);

    $widthColumn = '20';
    $activeWorksheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth($widthColumn);
    $activeWorksheet->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth($widthColumn);
    $activeWorksheet->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth($widthColumn);
    $activeWorksheet->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth($widthColumn);
    $activeWorksheet->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth($widthColumn);
    $activeWorksheet->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth($widthColumn);
    $activeWorksheet->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth($widthColumn);
    $activeWorksheet->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth($widthColumn);
    $activeWorksheet->getColumnDimension('I')->setWidth($widthColumn);

    $activeWorksheet->fromArray($fileArray);

    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);

    return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($writer) {
        $writer->save('php://output');
    }, 'profiles.xlsx', [
        'Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="profiles.xlsx"',
        'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
        'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT',
        'Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate',
        'Pragma: public'
    ]);
}
```